# Increase space between folders in nemo file manager Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: unity, nemo, 21.10

Ubuntu 21.10 was released today. After using Ubuntu 16.04 since it was released, I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10. Did a fresh install of 21.10. I like Unity desktop so I installed it and along with it I install Nemo file manager as well. Everything is working fine.

Just need one small help from you guys. Icon spacing is too low in Nemo file manager in Ubuntu 21.10. This is how it looks - [image]

But this is how it used to look in Ubuntu 16.04 -
[image]

Folders are too close in first image and also name of folders are wrapped in Ubuntu 21.10. Look at the folder named "eclipse-workspace". It's wrapped in Ubuntu 21.10 but not in Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I increase the space between folders and not let the text wrap like it is in Ubuntu 16.04?